# Meaning of Exact Transformation and $K$-Automorphism in the context of Ergodic Theory/Mixing

Tags: ergodic-theory, mixing

I am reading MAGIC$010$ Ergodic Theory course. In this course's lecture $4$ notes, it is mentioned that
$1)$ Let $T$ be an exact transformation of the probability space $(X,B,μ)$ .Then $T$ is strong-mixing.
$2)$ Let $T$ be a $K$-automorphism of the probability space $(X,B,μ)$.  Then $T$ is strong-mixing.

I understand what strong mixing, automorphism and transformation mean but I do not know what "Exact transformation" and "$K$-Automorphism" mean in this context. The author has not defined $K$ anywhere else so I'm not sure if that is a variable. Can someone clear this up? Thanks!

I can attach the link to the notes if required.

Comment: For those interested, the lecture notes can be found [here](https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/Charles.Walkden/magic/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These definitions can be found in [this article, page 11](http://www.im.ufrj.br/%7Egelfert/cursos/2018-2-TeoErg/Quas2011_ReferenceWorkEntry_ErgodicityAndMixingProperties.pdf).

$\ $

> **Definition:** A transformation $T$ of $(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$ is *exact* if $\cap^{\infty}_{n=0}T^{-n}\mathcal B$ consists entirely of null sets and sets of measure $1$.

$ \ $

> **Definition:** An invertible measure-preserving transformation $T$ of $(X, \mathcal B, \mu)$ is said to be $K$ (for Kolmogorov) if there is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ of $\mathcal B$ such that:
>
> 1. $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^{-n}\mathcal F$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra up to sets of measure $0$ (i. e. the intersection consists only of null sets and sets of full measure).
> 2. $\vee_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n\mathcal F = \mathcal B$ (i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $T^n \mathcal F$ for all $n>0$ is $\mathcal B$).

I would not worry that much about these, since they do not appear anywhere else in Charles' lecture notes for Ergodic Theory.

Comment: I actually wanted to prove that a transformation is Ergodic but it was claimed that proving that transformation is Strong-Mixing is actaully easier (even though it is a stronger claim)

Comment: Wikipedia article for $K$-Automorphisms also mentions that $F\subset TF$. Is that redundant?

Comment: @Anvit Fhew, you got me there! I would not be able to say stright away; maybe asking another question about this would be the most sensible thing to do, as I don't know the answer for this.